# Using namespaces in RegisterRoute (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, namespaces, routes

I have a solution with multiple projects. One of my projects only contains controllers. Another project contains my Views.

In my Views project, I've added namespaces in my RouteConfig.cs but I keep getting an error when I run my project:

> > Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

This is my RouteConfig.cs

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
                routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                namespaces: new[] { "AS.Core.Controllers" },
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

My HomeController.cs' namespace is `namespace AS.Core.Controllers.Home`

Setup:

Solution: AS.Core
-- Project: AS.Core.Controllers (controllers only)
-- Project: AS.Core.Web (views/scripts/css/images)

Under my controllers project I have multiple folders, such as "Home" and "Assets". I then have a controller in each folder so, I have "HomeController.cs" in the Home folder and "AssetsController.cs" in my Assets folder.

Comment: Why do you have the MVC model split between multiple projects?  How are the controllers supposed to find the models and views?  It is more than just a logical namespace that separates them.  It is a physical file/folder structure.

Comment: I've updated my original post and... That's the problem I'm having. My controllers do not see my views at all.

Comment: Do my controllers need to be in the same namespace as my Web? Such as, "AS.Core" for the namespace of both?

Comment: Your views are physical files.  MVC has a convention that needs to be followed and the views should be in the same project under a folder named `Views` I believe.  Like I said before.  There is more than just a namespace separating your controller from your view.  There is an actual physical structure that needs to be followed.

Comment: So I can't keep my controllers in a separate project from my views?

Comment: There is a way, but I don't think it is worth it. Not sure why you would want to either.  [MVC Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee307987%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Have you added a reference from your Web project to your controller project? That´s all you would need. Adding the namespaces in the route is usually needed when there is a collision like 2 controllers named HomeController in different namespaces (for example when having a HomeController for 2 or more areas)

Comment: You should be able to keep your views and controllers in two separate projects. You only need to ensure that your views project is a the web project and controllers project is referenced into this project. When project is deployed, you would get the usual views folder where all your views are

Comment: This may look little irrelevant but do you use `Resharper`?

Comment: I got it working. I was missing a reference and I do use ReSharper.

Thanks for the help.